# How to make sure two member of a Class are the same type

Tags: typescript, types

I have a class with a number of members.

I want to make sure two of them are the same type without knowing what type they are.

any Idea?

I've tried something like this, without any luck.

```
interface Foo {
  bar: Foo["baz"];
  baz: Foo["bar"];
}
```

Comment: There is no direct way to express such a thing; you'd be looking for *existentially quantified generics* but TS doesn't have these.  You can *encode* such types, but they're kind of a headache. What you would you actually do with a value of type `Foo` where `bar` and `baz` are "the same type you don't know about"?  I mean, I can write [this](https://tsplay.dev/w1Q0Ow) to encode that relationship, but I don't know what you'd ever do with `bar` and `baz`.  Swap them?  I'd love to see a real use case in a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might want to use [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html).

Something like this:

```
interface Foo<TMember> {
  bar: TMember;
  baz: TMember;
}
```

Here `TMember` is a placeholder for another type description. Instead of referring to the type `Foo` you would refer to, for example, `Foo<string>` for a version where `bar` and `baz` are both strings. You can use `Foo<unknown>` for the case where they could be anything.